# how to resolve this error in promtheus.yml file

Tags: linux, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

Facing error in promtheus.yml file

> "Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: line 7 field static config not found in type config.scrapeconfig

this is my prometheus.yml file

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'devopsage-monitor'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']   # your server ip
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'             
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']   # your server ip
```

Comment: I checked your configuration file with "promtool check config prometheus.yml" and it didn't find any error: "SUCCESS: prometheus.yml is valid prometheus config file syntax"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this configuration to solve this problem.

```html
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'devopsage-monitor'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: 
          - localhost:9090   # your server ip
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'             
    static_configs:
      - targets: 
          - localhost:9100   # your server ip
```